# AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'date'

Tags: python-3.x

I have no date in directory of datetime. I have `pip` installed datetime module too but its not working:

```
import datetime

    tday=datetime.date.today()
    print(tday)
```

Comment: Are you sure your python is correctly set up? What does `python3 -V` say?
 Also you may want to check the libraries loaded with `python3 -v` and the libraries installed with `pip3 list`.

Comment: Also, remember to always add [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 'its not working' is not a valid information about the issue you experience.

Answer (score -1):

I had pip installed many modules and it worked fine.Iam using 3.6.4.I install all modules in my script directory.

Answer (score -1):

I had pip installed many modules and it worked fine.I checked the libraried and it has datatime and datetime have date class also